Class of on-shell and gauge equivalent potentials in Chern-Simons theory
Let $(P, M, \pi, G)$ be a principal bundle with three dimensional manifold $M$ and compact, connected, simply-connected, and simple structure group $G$. We define a Lie algebra valued connection $1$ form on this data, whose local form is denoted $A$. We call $A$ a gauge potential. Consider classical Chern-Simons theory on this data.
The equation of motion obtained by stationizing the Chern-Simons action is
$$F = dA + A \wedge A = 0$$
and "gauge transformations" are given by
$$A \to D_XA = A+dX + A \wedge X$$
where $X$ is a $\mathfrak{g}$-valued $0$-form. We say $A$ is on-shell if it satisfies the equation of motion. We say that $A$ is gauge equivalent to $A'$ when $A - A' = dX + X\wedge A$, i.e. when $A$ and $A'$ are related by a gauge transformation.
If $G$ is abelian, then this simplifies to
$$dA = 0 \quad \text{and} \quad A \to A + dX.$$
In this case, the equivalence class of on-shell and gauge equivalent gauge potentials is an element in the first de Rham cohomology class of $M$. In other words, $H^1(M) = \ker d^2 / \text{im }d^1$ is the set of solutions to $dA = 0$ modulo gauge transformations.
If $G$ is not abelian, then we cannot immediately make an identification with a cohomology class. In particular, the map $D = d + A \wedge$ is not a coboundary map (does not square to the $0$ map). Given this, is there still an analogous (even cohomological) construction for the space of equivalence classes of on-shell and gauge equivalent gauge potentials in non-abelian Chern-Simons theory?
